# How can I get the raw html when an ajax call in jQuery hits error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get JSON data from another domain.
It returns status 200 but invokes an error in the callback function.
Is it possible to get the raw data or html or even just text when I get into the error callback?

Why is xhr.responseText undefined?

Here is part of my code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://timetable.nctu.edu.tw/?r=main/get_cos_list',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            async: false,
            data:{m_acy:'**',m_sem:'**',m_degree:'**',m_dep_id:'**',m_group:'**',
                  m_grade:'**',m_class:'**',m_option:'cos_code',m_crsname:'**',m_teaname:'**',
                  m_cos_id:'**',m_cos_code:'DAM1346',m_crstime:'**'},
            jsonp: true,
            success: function(json) {
                $('#jjjj').html(json);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#content').append("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"<br>status: "+xhr.status+"<br>responseText: "+xhr.responseText+"<br><hr>");

                alert('Ajax request error.' + xhr.responseText + xhr.responseData + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus)
            {
                alert(xhr.responseText + xhr.responseHtml);
                alert(h.responseHtml);
            }
        });
```

Comment: are you using a "modern browser" like chrome of firefox? then you can see everything within the developer-tools

Comment: Yeah, I use firefox, but I'm a beginner to web design.
I don't know what can I do...